# How to detect multiple objects in a frame using Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, object-detection

I have trained a model using keras with dataset of `airplane` `chair` and `cups`. It has trained well and is also detecting the objects perfectly fine. I have followed this [tutorial](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2020/10/12/multi-class-object-detection-and-bounding-box-regression-with-keras-tensorflow-and-deep-learning/)

During detection what I have noticed is that its only detecting one object in the frame. For ex, if there is airplane and chair both in the frame. It should ideally detect both but if just shows the one which high confidence only and not detecting both.

Below is the code I am using to detect

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import load_img
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
import numpy as np
import mimetypes
import argparse
import imutils
import pickle
import cv2
import os


imagePaths = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'test')
image_list = os.listdir(imagePaths)

model = load_model("output/detector.model")
lb = pickle.loads(open(config.LB_PATH, "rb").read())

for test_image in image_list:
    imagePath = os.path.join(imagePaths, test_image)
    image1 = cv2.imread(imagePath)
    image = load_img(imagePath, target_size=(224, 224))
    image = img_to_array(image) / 255.0
    image = np.expand_dims(image, axis=0)
    print(model.predict(image))
    (boxPreds, labelPreds) = model.predict(image)

    (startX, startY, endX, endY) = boxPreds[0]
    i = np.argmax(labelPreds, axis=1)
    label = lb.classes_[i][0]

    confidence = labelPreds.max()
    
    print(labelPreds.min())
    text = str(label + " " + str(confidence))

    image = cv2.imread(imagePath)
    image = imutils.resize(image, width=600)
    (h, w) = image.shape[:2]
    startX = int(startX * w)
    startY = int(startY * h)
    endX = int(endX * w)
    endY = int(endY * h)
    y = startY - 10 if startY - 10 > 10 else startY + 10
    cv2.putText(image, text, (startX, y), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.65, (0, 255, 0), 2)
    cv2.rectangle(image, (startX, startY), (endX, endY), (0, 255, 0), 2)

    cv2.imshow("Output", image)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

How can I update the model so that while predicting, it can predict multiple objects in the frame. Please help. THanks

Comment: You are only drawing one box (the first one), so asking about multiple objects is kind of moot.

Answer (score 0):

I only have a guess, could it be that the boxPreds array has more predictions in it?

```
(startX, startY, endX, endY) = boxPreds[0]
```

Try this:

```
for x in range len(boxPreds):
    (startX, startY, endX, endY) = boxPreds[x]
    i = np.argmax(labelPreds, axis=1)
    label = lb.classes_[i][x]


    confidence = labelPreds.max()
    
    print(labelPreds.min())
    text = str(label + " " + str(confidence))

    image = cv2.imread(imagePath)
    image = imutils.resize(image, width=600)
    (h, w) = image.shape[:2]
    startX = int(startX * w)
    startY = int(startY * h)
    endX = int(endX * w)
    endY = int(endY * h)
    y = startY - 10 if startY - 10 > 10 else startY + 10
    cv2.putText(image, text, (startX, y), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.65, (0, 255, 0), 2)
    cv2.rectangle(image, (startX, startY), (endX, endY), (0, 255, 0), 2)

cv2.imshow("Output", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Not tested, but I hope you get the idea.